# im unable to attache pdf, doc files in android 11 using filepicker using xamarin forms

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

when I attaché pdf, doc file  getting the following exception.

`````
 ``` ex = {Java.Lang.NullPointerException: uri at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallNonvirtualObjectMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniObjectReference type, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValu...````
`````

please help on this I m new to this Xamarin forms.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: you need to show us your code that is causing this exception

Comment: How do you attache the file? Send email? Could you share the code for us for more details?

Comment: `private async void AttachFile_TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                 var file = await CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile();       
Getting the exception the above line when i attached pdf and doc file.        
                if (file != null)
                {
                    var byteData = file.DataArray;   
                }`